# resolution of many to many in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm re-asking this as I'm still confused, so I've also added some edits.

With a many to many relationship, an intersection table is used to resolve this to two one-to-many relationships. My problem here is that I currently have 2 tables, "Playlist" and "song". Each song be present in many playlists, and each playlist can contain many songs. To resolve this add a third table, "songlog" to resolve the many to many.

I understand this much, however, when it comes to adding values into the database, I can't get my head around populating the tables to relate the three together.. For example, how would I add some (e.g 4) songs into the playlist table, using the intersection table? Also, how would I then add the details of which songs are in which playlist? As I currently see it, I would use the primary keys of both "Playlist" and "song", in the intersection table, but I'm unsure as to where, how, and why.

I'm still confused, so a clear and basic explanation of this area of design may help! Many thanks.

Comment: You're right, the insertsection table lists the primary key(s) of both related tables. Those columns on itself, become the combined (at least 2) primary key columns of the intersection table. In addition, the intersection can have data columns, BUT you must always take in mind that ANY data column either is directly related to object A (in your case song), or directly related to object B (playlist), or directly related to the relation between object A and object B. ANY data column is either directly linked to one of those 3, without exception. This is what the relational database is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is what your DDL (data definition language) would look like, with some example inserts:

```
create table playlist
(
  playlist_id numeric(10) not null,
  playlist_name varchar(25),
     constraint p_id_pk primary key (playlist_id)
);

create table songs
(
  song_id numeric(10) not null,
  song_name varchar(25),
     constraint s_id_pk primary key (song_id)
);

create table playlist_songs
(
  playlist_id,
  song_id,
  song_order int,
     constraint p_fk foreign key (playlist_id) references playlist(playlist_id),
     constraint s_fk foreign key (song_id) references songs(song_id)
);

insert into playlist values (1, 'A cool playlist');
insert into playlist values (2, 'An okay playlist');

insert into songs values (1, 'ABC');
insert into songs values (2, 'DEF');
insert into songs values (3, 'GHI');
insert into songs values (4, 'JKL');

insert into playlist_songs values (1, 1, 1);
insert into playlist_songs values (1, 3, 2);

insert into playlist_songs values (2, 2, 1);
insert into playlist_songs values (2, 3, 2);
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0420f/5/0

And an example of a SELECT query you might run:

```
select ps.playlist_id,
       p.playlist_name,
       s.song_id,
       s.song_name,
       ps.song_order
  from playlist_songs ps
  join songs s
    on ps.song_id = s.song_id
  join playlist p
    on ps.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
 order by ps.playlist_id, ps.song_order
```

Output:

```
| PLAYLIST_ID |    PLAYLIST_NAME | SONG_ID | SONG_NAME | SONG_ORDER |
|-------------|------------------|---------|-----------|------------|
|           1 |  A cool playlist |       1 |       ABC |          1 |
|           1 |  A cool playlist |       3 |       GHI |          2 |
|           2 | An okay playlist |       2 |       DEF |          1 |
|           2 | An okay playlist |       3 |       GHI |          2 |
```

The purpose of the intermediary table is data normalization. It reduces the amount of data you store and allows greater control over the data.

In the system, you have a library of songs. Users can create playlists and assign songs to those playlists. You have songs, playlists, and assignments of songs to playlists.

That information could be combined in a denormalized fashion (such as in the query result above) but denormalized data is primarily meant for reporting. When you are storing data, you don't want to store the same data in multiple locations. You should not see the name of a playlist stored in two places. Or a song's name stored in two places. You would be storing redundant data. Also when something changes, say the size of a song (not currently included in your schema, but could be), it would obviously be ideal to be able to update just 1 row of the songs table, as opposed to potentially thousands of rows on any sort of denormalized table.

Denormalized tables do have their place in reporting environments, because they involve fewer table joins when selecting data for reporting and analysis. The tables are wider and contain information users frequently look for in their queries. Likewise, partitioning can also yield significant performance gains when running certain queries.

Answer (score 3):

You must make make the difference between inserting songs and playlists and linking them together. First always insert the missing songs and playlists

```
INSERT INTO song (SongID, Name) VALUES (7, 'New song 1');
INSERT INTO song (SongID, Name) VALUES (8, 'New song 2');

INSERT INTO playlist (PlaylistID, Name) VALUES (15, 'The new playlist`);
```

Once your songs and playlists are complete, you can link them together:

```
INSERT INTO songlog (SongID, PlaylistID) VALUES (7, 15);
INSERT INTO songlog (SongID, PlaylistID) VALUES (8, 15);
```

This adds song 7 and song 8 to the playlist 15. You can add one song to another playlist as well (assuming that there is a palylist #33 in the playlists table already):

```
INSERT INTO songlog (SongID, PlaylistID) VALUES (7, 33);
```

You don't have to insert the song into the songs table again. Each song and each playlist exits exactly once.

---

This assumes the following table structures

```
Table song
----------
PK SongID
   Name

Table playlist
--------------
PK PlaylistID
   Name

Table songlog
-------------
PK FK SongID
PK FK PlaylistID
```

`PK` means *Primary Key* and `FK` means *Foreign Key*.

Answer (score 1):

If your table `PLAYLIST` has primary key `PLAYLIST_ID`, and your table `SONG` has primary key `SONG_ID`, then the intersection table `SONGLOG` (I'm not sure that's a particularly good name for the table, perhaps try something else like `PLAYLIST_SONG`) should have a primary key consisting of `PLAYLIST_ID` and `SONG_ID`. It could have an additional column, say `SONG_ORDER`, so that the songs could be ordered for the playlist.

Suppose you have the following playlist:

```
PLAYLIST_ID  PLAYLIST_NAME
1            David's Songs
```

and the following songs:

```
SONG_ID  SONG_NAME
1        Big Country
2        She Hangs Brightly
```

then you might add those songs to `SONGLOG` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO songlog ( playlist_id, song_id, song_order )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 1 );

INSERT INTO songlog ( playlist_id, song_id, song_order )
VALUES ( 1, 2, 2 );
```

Hope this helps.